# php function to encode strange string to normal hebrew

Tags: php, encoding

I have this string " ×ª××¨×× ×©××¨××¨ " and i want to turn it to normal hebrew "תאריך שחרור" using php.

Please help me to find the right function.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using utf8 charset in your scripts first off and you should not have that problem.  If utf8 isn't viable, at least use it for form submission then use utf8_decode($string) to convert it.  If that doesn't help look into iconv functions on php.net.

Comment: doesn't work.. i have this string as is. I have to switch it.. i can't control the process before